# Entire SQL query as variable in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have several queries to be run on a customer table. Each of these queries identifies possible data quality issues in the customer table. For example, one query is to find if a customer's age is < 18, which cannot / should not be the case.

I have a cursor that fetches each of these queries one by one into a variable.

I am struggling to run each of these queries and aggregate the results.

```
DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT [ruleQuery] FROM [dbo].[SQL_DataQuality_Rules]
OPEN rules_cursor    
FETCH NEXT FROM rules_cursor INTO @rulequery
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --Help needed here to execute @rulequery which would be something like
    --SELECT sum(case when age < 18 then 1 else 0 end) as 'Fail' FROM...
FETCH NEXT FROM rules_cursor INTO @rulequery
END
CLOSE c1
DEALLOCATE c1
```

Since I would be calling this procedure from excel, I would like to have all the fail counts in one table in excel.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/dynamicsql/

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to put contraints on the table so that these conditions cannot be put into the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose each of your queries has as a result a table with two columns: title, fail. Your queries only have one column (fail) but you wouldn't know what is failing from that output. Change to have them return a title column as well. What you do:

1. Create a table variable or a temporary table with those same columns
2. Insert the output from executing the SQL Queries into the table variable or temporary table
3. After the loop, select the contents of the table variable or temporary table as the result of your Stored Procedure.

Example:

```
DECLARE @res TABLE(title VARCHAR(256), fail INT);

DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT [ruleQuery] FROM [dbo].[SQL_DataQuality_Rules];
OPEN rules_cursor;
DECLARE @rulequery VARCHAR(MAX);
FETCH NEXT FROM rules_cursor INTO @rulequery;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  --Query like: SELECT 'Age check' AS title, sum(case when age < 18 then 1 else 0 end) as 'Fail' FROM...
  INSERT INTO @res(title,fail) EXEC (@rulequery);
  FETCH NEXT FROM rules_cursor INTO @rulequery;
END
CLOSE c1;
DEALLOCATE c1;

SELECT*FROM @res;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code inside the cursor will do your job. but dont forget to declare @rulequery variable

```
IF LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@rulequery)))>0
EXEC(@rulequery)
```